# Como hacer que Angular 2 sepa a través de qué URL se realiza la petición

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Angular 2 del lado del cliente y Node del lado del servidor con MongoDB de base de datos.

Los datos que están almacenados en MongoDB son datos geográficos que están categorizados por zonas, cada documento lleva, entre otras cosas, un campo **zone** que le identifica dentro de una zona.

```
{ ..., zone: "R04",...}
```

Los datos que a través de la API hecha en Node llegan a Angular 2 pueden ser de una zona o de otra según le interese al usuario.

La idea es que el usuario al escribir la URL establezca la zona que le interesa a través de un parámetro, de la siguiente forma:

```
www.dominio.com/zone/R04
```

En el ejemplo el usuario nos indica que le interesa la zona **R04** .

Mi duda es como hacer que la aplicación Angular sepa que el usuario ha realizado la petición estableciendo una zona determinada, en el caso del ejemplo la zona R04, para que posteriormente la aplicación cliente consulte a la API de Node solo datos referentes a la zona en cuestión.

Comment: Esto se logra a través del enrutamiento con parámetros, sugiero leer https://medium.com/@yonem9/angular-cómo-se-pasan-datos-entre-urls-1a9ec5d779ea, creo te puede ayudar mucho a entender el tema.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace!. No es exactamente lo que necesito ya que el router de Angular, sino me equivoco, funciona una vez descargada la aplicación cliente. La idea es que la aplicación cliente se descargue sabiendo a través de qué URL ha sido a petición inicial. Es como por ejemplo escribir en la barra de direcciones, sin tener la aplicación cliente Angular descargada,  www.tienda.com/list/products/ y que la aplicación Angular, en este momento, se descargue sabiendo que el usuario ha tecleado de primeras la URL www.tienda.com/list/products/ y muestre, en base a la URL, un listado de productos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar el enrutamiento de angular, el usuario final puede digitar la URL incluyendo el parámetro, no es necesario que previamente se realice el cargue de la aplicación. Angular procesará la petición cargando la pagina vinculada al enrutamiento (adicionalmente todo lo demás que necesite) y tomando el valor suministrado. Para mas detalle de como usar el enrutamiento sugiero leer: [https://medium.com/@yonem9/angular-cómo-se-pasan-datos-entre-urls-1a9ec5d779ea](https://medium.com/@yonem9/angular-c%C3%B3mo-se-pasan-datos-entre-urls-1a9ec5d779ea)

Comment: Perfecto!, pensaba que primero necesitaba la carga inicial para luego "hacer caso" al router. Gracias!